# akka (2.0.5) micorkernel can not stay up for unknown reason on amazon ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, akka

I have a problem recently for even a simple akka microkernel model app. it can not stay up on amazon ec2. Here is the log

---

```
Starting Akka...
Running Akka 2.0.5
Deploying file:/data/akka-scala/akka-2.0.5/deploy/catchif2_2.9.2-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[DEBUG] [03/02/2013 09:35:32.626] [main] [EventStream] StandardOutLogger started
[DEBUG] [03/02/2013 09:35:33.415] [main] [EventStream(akka://hellokernel)] logger log1-Slf4jEventHandler started
[DEBUG] [03/02/2013 09:35:33.416] [main] [EventStream(akka://hellokernel)] Default Loggers started
Starting up com.catchif.HelloKernel
Successfully started Akka

Shutting down Akka...
Shutting down com.catchif.HelloKernel
Received message 'HELLO world!'
Successfully shut down Akka
```

---

Basically it starts up and shutdown automatically immediately.

I run the same code on my mac. it stay up perfectly. There is no extra info in the log  other than this:

```
03/02 09:35:33 INFO [hellokernel-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] a.e.s.Slf4jEventHandler - Slf4jEventHandler started
03/02 09:35:33 DEBUG[hellokernel-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] a.e.EventStream - logger log1-Slf4jEventHandler started
03/02 09:35:33 DEBUG[hellokernel-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] a.e.EventStream - Default Loggers started
```

The code is very simple as well.

---

```
import akka.actor.{ Actor, ActorSystem, Props }
import akka.kernel.Bootable

case object Start

class HelloActor extends Actor {
  val worldActor = context.actorOf(Props[WorldActor])

  def receive = {
    case Start ⇒ worldActor ! "Hello"
    case message: String ⇒
      println("Received message '%s'" format message)
  }
}

class WorldActor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case message: String ⇒ sender ! (message.toUpperCase + " world!")
  }
}

class HelloKernel extends Bootable {
  val system = ActorSystem("hellokernel")

  def startup = {
    system.actorOf(Props[HelloActor]) ! Start
  }

  def shutdown = {
    system.shutdown()
  }
}
```

---

Not sure why it happens. and I did see it stayed up on amazon for one time but it fails all the time later.

Thanks in advance,
Best,
James

Answer (score 0):

Try this and tell me what happens:

```
class HelloKernel extends App {
  val system = ActorSystem("hellokernel")
  system.actorOf(Props[HelloActor]) ! Start
}
```

This is a minimalist implementation and should hold the bash shell until you hit ctrl-c. If that works then I would say something is off with your extension of the Bootable class (something you are missing).